# Hydra http connection failed

Tags: linux, bash, security, hydra

I want to check my page that only have one **ip** without hostname`(http://ip.ip.ip.ip/dologin.htm)`

Now I want to check it for brute force from `hydra`.

What I tried is:

```
hydra -l admin  -p admin ip.ip.ip.ip http-post-form "/dologin.htm:P2=^PASS^&Login=:1"
```

`P2`: form of password

`LOGIN`: form of username(This is empty - no user name )

`:1`: for bad password attempting(doesn't have message for entering bad password)...

So the result is:

When I enter correct password in `hydra` it says your password is wrong ...

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: could you please post the html code of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you failur condition (`:1`).

From the [source](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/master/hydra-http-form.c) we can see that the format for option field is as follows:

> The option field (following the service field) takes three ":" separated
>   values and an optional fourth value, the first is the page on the server
>   to GET or POST to, the second is the POST/GET variables (taken from either
>   the browser, or a proxy such as PAROS) with the varying usernames and passwords
>   in the "^USER^" and "^PASS^" placeholders, the third is the string that it
>   checks for an *invalid* or *valid* login - any exception to this is counted
>   as a success.
>   So please:
>    * invalid condition login should be preceded by "F="
>    * valid condition login should be preceded by "S=".
>   By default, if no header is found the condition is assume to be a fail,
>   so checking for *invalid* login.
>   The fourth optional value, can be a 'C' to define a different page to GET
>   initial cookies from.

So you should be able to supply a `success` condition instead of a `fail` condition.

Therefore change your `:1` to `:S=string from the page after successful login`.